# bash script failing to use ssh -i. Can't see directory

Tags: shell-script, ssh, osx

I am experiencing something strange. I am working on a script to remote install Splunk on servers via a script. In this script I ssh to my practice servers (5 amazon EC2 instances running Redhat).

However, when I run the script I get this error:

`Warning: Identity file ~/Keypairs/jadam-macbookpro-ec2-1.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.`

My first step was to obviously make sure that the path was there. I copy the command run and paste it into my terminal. I successfully connect to my instance using the keypair.

Here is the command in question. I have tried it both with and without sudo prefixing the command:

```
KEYPAIR="~/Keypairs/jadam-macbookpro-ec2-1.pem"
sudo ssh -i "$KEYPAIR" "$DST" "$REMOTE_SCRIPT"
```

REMOTE_SCRIPT is the script file to run, and DST is my server addresses pulled from a hosts file.

The resolved command is:

```
ssh -i ~/Keypairs/jadam-macbookpro-ec2-1.pem ec2-user@12.3.4.567
```

The script fails, but copying the command and doing it manually works. I thought it was a permissions issue at first, which is why I ran it with sudo, but it thinks the directory doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `~` to `$HOME`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually your resolved command isn't right. It's really this:

```
ssh -i "~/Keypairs/jadam-macbookpro-ec2-1.pem" "ec2-user@12.3.4.567"
```

The double quotes stop the shell expanding `~` and it's treated there as a literal (passed directly on to `ssh`). Replace it with the environment variable `$HOME` and the problem will resolve itself:

```
KEYPAIR="$HOME/Keypairs/jadam-macbookpro-ec2-1.pem"
sudo ssh -i "$KEYPAIR" "$DST" "$REMOTE_SCRIPT"
```

I should point out that `ssh` will evaluate the `~` as *home directory*, but in this case it will be doing so in root's context rather than yours, so will not be looking for the file in your `$HOME/.ssh` directory.